# Batch Multiple Active Remote desktop sessions

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

I want to see if mutliple active remote desktop sessions are running on my client PC using a batch script.

When I open my [Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di1SP.png) I can see a `(2)` behind `MSTSC.exe`

I already used:

```
wmic process where name="mstsc.exe" | find "mstsc.exe" /c
```

But the result I get is `1` even if there are two remote desktop sessions active.

I wonder if anyone can help me with this challenge.

Comment: Have you tried that command without piping the output? `wmic process where name="mstsc.exe"`. Now based on that output, what do you think `find /c` is looking at?

Comment: if you want to stay with `wmic` (see Compo's answer), then: `wmic process where name="mstsc.exe" get /value |find /c "Caption"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a simpler method:

```bat
TaskList|Find /I /C "mstsc.exe"
```

To save the number as a variable in a batch file:

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('TaskList^|Find /I /C "mstsc.exe"') Do @Set "Num=%%A"
@Echo %Num%
```

If you still wished to use `WMIC` for the task then perhaps you could change your provided example to:

```bat
WMIC Process Where Name="mstsc.exe" Get Name | Find /I /C "mstsc.exe"
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. unfortunately this was not the solution even though two remote desktop sessions are open it will indicate this as one program ( mstsc.exe ). But your methode/code was indeed better.

Comment: @Batchman, which method sees the process only once, the `TaskList` version, the `WMIC` version or both?

Comment: WMIC sees the process once and the tasklist will display (2).

Comment: @Batchman, If the TaskList displays `2` then my answer is correct, is it not? Do you just want me to remove the `WMIC` answer so that you can mark my answer as the accepted solution?